# Способы инъекции в Spring 3.

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. По-тихоньку изучаю `Spring 3 MVC`, и наткнулся на такую штуку, как `@Inject`. Я прекрасно понял, что она делает инъекцию в создаваемый класс (например, класс контроллера). Далее, начал разбираться, откуда берется инициализированный класс. И нашел только, что он объявляется в контексте приложения (**app-context.xml**). И там-же, в этом *xml*-файле, указываем параметры, которые надо закинуть в сеттер-методы этого класса. Вот так:

```
<bean id="someId" class="rct.gomel.beans.MyClass">
    <property name="pole_class" value="мае валюэ"/>
</bean>
```

Все это даже очень понятно. Но неужели можно инъектить *только* таким способом??? Если да, то напрашивается такой вопрос:

Не легче ли просто в этом классе, куда надо инъектить сделать так:

```
@Controller//Означает, что это контроллер.
public class NewController {
    private MyClass class = new MyClass("параметр1", параметр_2, 52);
    ... ... ...
```

Все равно же и так и так результат будет одинаков.
Я просто не совсем улавливаю смысла, зачем реализовали такую возможность, тратили на это время?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Касательно `new` и инъекции: ваш вопрос происходит из-за недостаточного понимания главной концепции на которой построен весь Spring -- [инъекция зависимостей (`Dependency Injection`)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection). Ваш пример сам по себе не очень удачен, потому что вся сила внедрения зависимостей раскрывается при использовании интерфейсов. В таком случае вы в своём классе объявляете переменную с типом нужного интерфейса, а Spring подставляет необходимую имплементацию этого интерфейса. Т.о. ваш код не зависит от конкретной реализации (меньше связность) и вы в любой момент можете поменять реализацию этого класса, не изменяя класс(ы), в которых он используется.

Кроме того, Spring также следит и за областью жизни объекта (т.е. `Scope`). Например, все бины по умолчанию имеют `Singleton scope`, что означает, что они всегда представлены в единственном экземпляре.

Естественно, что это не все плюсы и удобства, которые даёт эта технология.

Кстати, `@Inject` в Spring-е поддерживается, но скорее ради совместимости с JSR-330, в большинстве же случаев используется "родной" `@Autowired`.

Рекомендую прочитать [официальную документацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) (на английском) про бины, устройство контейнера, контекст и как это всё работает.

> Я уже начинаю сомневаться в правильности моего выбора изучать Spring. Потому что, как видно, мало Spring-специалистов (только один ответ). И следовательно, Spring мало нужен.

То что на этом ресурсе мало "Spring-специалистов" отнюдь не означает, что "Spring мало нужен". Просто часть специалистов не ходит по форумам, другая читает англоязычные форумы, а третья предпочитает общаться на других русскоязычных ресурсах.

Comment: +1, кроме того, в больших системах плюсом становится наглядность связей между различными компонентами. И пусть вас не смущают скупые ответы неопытного разработчика ввиде меня - наоборот, кажется, Spring является в некотором роде мейнстримом. Я успел поучаствовать всего в трех проектах с Java на сервере, но во всех них он в той или иной степени использовался (команды были разные).

Comment: Ну все ясно. Это один из плюсов, и ясно, в чем он заключается. Спасибо за хороший ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, возможно, я не так понял вопрос, но для меня он может быть переформулирован так: зачем использовать Dependency Injection? Если отвечать в этом предположении, то для меня самые очевидные плюсы:

- большая гибкость в тестировании (для любого случая можно изменить конфигурацию без надобности менять main код);
- свойств может быть много, конструкторов на всех не напасешься.

Говоря о DI, принято рассказывать об архитектурных улучшениях и проч., но лично для меня то, что я привел - самое ясное (возможно, это связано с тем, что я не разрабатывал крупных приложений без использования DI).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если много параметров, то  можно так
{
  object.setField1(Значение);
  object.setField1(Значение);
  object.setField1(Значение);
  object.setField1(Значение);
}.
А Вы работали со Spring 3? Там только так можно Injection делать? Или еще как-то?

Comment: Я уже начинаю сомневаться в правильности моего выбора изучать Spring. Потому что, как видно, мало Spring-специалистов и только один ответ. И следовательно, Spring мало нужен.

Comment: 2 @Антон Мухин во всех мануалах по по spring орут что это мега просто и мега быстро, но все просто и быстро ровно до тех пор пока решаеш задачи уровня тех что описаны в мануалах.   
я лично ненахожу его простым, ни в понимании, ни в использовании. возможно когда есть готовый проэкт на spring то это действительно просто поменять одну строчку в конфигурационном файле, с другой стороны система которая вся построена на интерфейсах сама по себе гибкая (+шаблоны) и без проблем можно заменить класс и в коде.
p.s. лично меня утомляют проэкты где 100500 конфигурационных файлов для разных плюшек